# How do I use play framework 2's json path to parse json that has been poorly converted from xml?

Tags: xml, json, scala, deserialization, playframework-2.1

I've got an incoming data feed of the form:

```
{ attributes: [
 { name:"first", values=["1st"]},
 { name:"second", values=["2a", "2b"]}
]}
```

I want to parse this into a case class of the form:

```
case class TheThing(first:String, second:List[String])
```

All the examples of the json path reads operations I've seen only involve quite a direct mapping from one node to one property, how do I handle operations where there are multiple nodes and in some cases conversions from lists to singulars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I've come up with is no good for performance intensive code, however it presents a clean interface for mapping.

```
object ThingReads {
  def reads(source:JsValue) = {
    val names:Seq[String] = (source \ "attributes" \\ "name").map(_.as[String])
    val values:Seq[JsValue] = source \ "attributes" \\ "values"
    val read = reads[TheThing] = (
      ( __ \ "first")(0).as[String] and
      ( __ \ "second").as[List[String]]
    )(TheThing.apply _)
    JsObject(names.zip(values)).as[TheThing](read)
  }
}
```

The major negatives being that you're required to iterate the json tree twice two build the "nicer form" json, then again when you extract your values.

Also if your key-value pair collection (attributes in this case) has a lot of irrelevant data in it, you're paying the price for transforming that data along with the bits you want to extract.

I'm going to accept this answer as it solves the problem, but I'll keep coming back to see if someone can provide a superior solution (I'm confident there's one out there and I'd love to learn it)